# How to a convert a date to a number and back again in MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab, date

I have the date 
1/11/2010

and use the function

= date(year(A1),month(A1),day(A1))

to convert the date to the number to 40189 with Excel.

Can I use MATLAB to convert the number 40189 back to the date again?

Answer (score 11):

Use [DATESTR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/datestr.html)

```
>> datestr(40189)
ans =
12-Jan-0110
```

Unfortunately, Excel starts counting at 1-Jan-1900. Find out how to convert serial dates from Matlab to Excel by using [DATENUM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/datenum.html)

```
>> datenum(2010,1,11)
ans =
      734149
>> datenum(2010,1,11)-40189
ans =
      693960
>> datestr(40189+693960)
ans =
11-Jan-2010
```

In other words, to convert any serial Excel date, call

```
datestr(excelSerialDate + 693960)
```

**EDIT**

To get the date in mm/dd/yyyy format, call `datestr` with the specified format

```
excelSerialDate = 40189;
datestr(excelSerialDate + 693960,'mm/dd/yyyy')
ans =
01/11/2010
```

Also, if you want to get rid of the leading zero for the month, you can use [REGEXPREP](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/regexprep.html) to fix things

```
excelSerialDate = 40189;
regexprep(datestr(excelSerialDate + 693960,'mm/dd/yyyy'),'^0','')
ans =
1/11/2010
```

Comment: Note that some Excel files start their epoch at 1904, not 1900. (See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/180162) If you're writing generic Excel/Matlab date conversion code, you'll need to either test for or provide an input to indicate the 1904 special case. The datenum offset is 695422 for 1904 epoch Excel files.