# Prevent Excel from Changing Text to Number

Tags: sql, excel, sqlite

I am trying to write an sql script to populate a database using Excel *[OP is trying to use Excel to compose a valid SQL statement]*, it is working perfect with one exception. I need to enter the dates in the following format `, '1971-10-02'`. As soon as I add the comma and single quotes, it changes the date to a number. It can be done manually but I have a number of records so I used a formula.

`=CHAR(44) & CHAR(32) & CHAR(39) & ScriptSQL!L5 &CHAR(39)`

How can I make Exel change 1971-10-02 into `, '1971-10-02'` and prevent `, '26208'`?

When I pre-format the cell as text it displays =CHAR(44) & CHAR(32) & CHAR(39) & ScriptSQL!L5 &CHAR(39).

Thank you.

Comment: How is SQL involved here? It doesn't make a lot of sense. Also, this is looking like an out-of-topic question, better suited for superuser.com

Comment: Format it in your SQL statement using `CAST` or `CONVERT` or whatever is supported in your database engine. I'd try to be more specific, but you didn't ask about SQL (even though you used the tag), and simply asked a generic Excel user question that should be on [su] instead; it has nothing to do with programming or programmers tools.

Comment: Why is it when I ask a question here it turns in a debate over the topic, where it is placed, etc? I try my best to place questions where they should go. Sometimes it is not as obvious as it should be. I was looking at Excel questions and I tried to use common sense and asked a question on. So as for the SQL part, it has to do with SQL because I am writing an sql script that needs a comma, and a single quote on either end of the date or it will not work.

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake it should have gone to Super User. I have never used CAST or CONVERT, but after a quick check sqlite does not have a date type, it is stored as text.

Comment: Oh, now I get what you're trying to do. The way the question is phrased, it does not appear to involve programming at all. What you're probably looking for is `=", '" & TEXT(ScriptSQL!L5,"yyyy-MM-dd") &"'"`.

Comment: How can it be moved to Super User?

Comment: Perfect! Euro, put that up as the answer. Thanks, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the question is phrased, it does not appear to involve programming at all. I made a couple of edits to clarify what you were trying to do.

What you're probably looking for is this:

```
=", '" & TEXT(ScriptSQL!L5, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "'"
```

Comment: Again, perfect, thanks for the help. This will save me a lot of time.

Comment: No worries on the edits, they make sense and clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel a date such as 1971-10-02 is converted to an integer.  If you set the date as a string literal ="1971-10-02" then it will be stored as a string.

If you're trying to pull it out of Excel but can't change whether it's a date or string in Excel, you need to [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954216/how-to-a-convert-a-date-to-a-number-and-back-again-in-matlab) it from and integer to a date string.

Comment: The problem is I have about a thousand dates. And I need a more timely approach than typing in all those dates again. I have not tried pulling it out of Excel yet. If the format is not correct I do not quite see the point.