# Handling very large matlab file

Tags: matlab

I have a legacy Matlab code on WINDOWS 7 which I can't change.

It reads a CSV input file of the format:

```
SNo    Date         Qty 
1      41640        100 
2      41641        150
```

and does whatever it needs to do.

But I have a new version of CSV file which instead has format:

```
SNo    Date            Qty  
1      1/1/2013        100  
2      1/2/2013        150
```

The CSV files are massive so it is impossible to change the date column to number format by opening CSV file in excel. So, I am thinking about using Matlab to generate a file with modified second column as excel number and make it readable for legacy code.

So, How do I accomplish the above generation of new CSV file to be readable into legacy code.

Comment: Windows 7 (just added that to question as well)

Comment: Is date-conversion the issue or reading / writing the csv-files?

Comment: I don't know how to do date conversion for such massive file in excel and I don't know an efficient way to read old CSV file and create a new CSV file. What do you suggest is a good solution. :)

Comment: Use `datenum` to convert.

Comment: How exactly datenum helps my situation ? My problem is not, not knowing what datenum is.

Comment: Do the dates in the example reflect real values? I.e. can you tell that 1/1/2013 corresponds to 41640?

Comment: Check `doc datenum`. In MATLAB it represents the fractional number of days since a certain date. Your "old" format seems to be the same, just with a different start-date.

Comment: Excel and Matlab have a different idea of what "day 1" is - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954216/how-to-a-convert-a-date-to-a-number-and-back-again-in-matlab . Thus you need to adjust for the difference (which sebastian's code attempts to do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying Sebastian's answer to do it "all at once":

```
fin = fopen('csv_input.csv');
fout = fopen('csv_out.csv', 'w');

rawData = textscan(fin, "%d %i/%i/%i %i', Inf); % <<< read all at once
matlabDates = datenum(rawData(:,[4 3 2])); % <<< check that this works as expected
excelDates = m2xdate(matlabDates);
outputArray = [rawData[:,1] excelDates rawData(:,5)];
fprintf(fout, '%i %i %i\n", outputArray);  % <<< check that this works as expected

fclose(fin);
fclose(fout);
```

I could not test this - so pay attention to the results of the three lines with `<<<` to make sure the format is what is expected (for example - is `rawData` a cell array?)

This might be slightly more efficient than Sebastian's answer at the expense of having the entire array in memory at once.

Answer (score 1):

You could e.g. do the following;

```
fin = fopen('csv_input.csv');
fout = fopen('csv_out.csv', 'w+');

offset = datenum([2013,1,1,0,0,0]) - 41640;

dvec = zeros(1,6);
while ~feof(fid)
    l = fgetl(fidn);
    % parse line by line
    nums = sscanf(l, '%i %i/%i/%i %i')';
    dvec(1:3) = nums([4,2,3]);
    % convert to datenum using the calculated offset
    date = datenum(dvec) - offset;
    fprintf(fout, '%i %i %i\n', nums(1), date, nums(5));
end

fclose(fin);
fclose(fout);
```

Disclaimer: untested ;)

Comment: You didn't mean `date = datenum(datenum([2013,1,1,0,0,0])) - offset;` did you? I am guessing you want `date = datenum(datenum([dvec 0 0 0])) - offset;` . Same disclaimer!

Comment: I will use m2xdate(datenum('1/1/2014')) as I need the dates to be in excel number format. There is no offset here.

Comment: I don't know the finance toolbox where `m2xdate` if coming from. But if that already exists, it's surely better tested than my version. Though for completeness - it won't do anything else than subtract an offset. Only where the offset comes from is different.

Comment: I want to avoid line by line parsing but seems that is the only way out ?

Comment: You could modify the above from using `fgetl`and `sscanf` to using `fscanf` (check the doc on that). This will scan the full file and return all parsed numbers into `nums`. Since you called the csv-files "massive" this might however become an isssue memory-wise - since you'll have all csv-data in memory at once. It really depends on what "massive" means in terms of bytes...

Comment: There are efficient matlab routines to read, process, and write the entire file at once - but if you are having difficulty opening the file in Excel I am not sure it would be that much better (which is presumably why @sebastian gave you a line by line solution). How many lines is "massive"?